# Reordering python list based on an algorithm or pattern

Tags: python, algorithm, list, math

Here is a stumper for you math geeks out there.

I have a python list that is just a sequence that looks like this:

```
myList=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,(...etc...),43]
```

Unfortunately, the data from which the list was generated was not zero-padded, and it should have been.  So in reality:

```
1==1
2==10
3==11
4==12
5==13
6==14
7==15
8==16
9==17
10==18
11==19
12==2
13==20
14==21
etc. until
34==4
35==40
36==41
37==42
38==43
39==5
40==6
41==7
42==8
43==9
```

Is there a way that I can remap this list based on the pattern described above.  Keep in mind that the list I expect can range from 10-90 items.

Thanks.

*edit for clarification:*

The list is derived from an XML file with a list of nodes in order:

```
<page>1</page>
<page>2</page>
etc...
```

The process that produced the XML used some input data that SHOULD have been zero-padded, but was not.  So as a result, what is listed in the XML file as 2 should be interpreted as 10.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Can you explain the desired mapping in words ?  I can't figure it out from what you have posted. What, for example, is '**2**' supposed to represent ?  Where should the data have been padded with 0s ?

Comment: @High: The values on the rhs are the strings representing the numbers 1..43, in lexicographical order. Assuming that `**2**` means `2`, and the stars are just some kind of emphasis.

Comment: Sorry, the **2** was a typo...it should have just been 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate the list that contains the broken position, then look at the indices to find the new position.

```
brokenlist = sorted(range(1, 44), key=str)
brokenmap = [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(sorted(range(1, 44), key=str)), key=lambda x: x[1])]
fixedlist = [brokenlist[x] for x in brokenmap]
```

Comment: `brokenmap = sorted(xrange(len(brokenlist)), key=brokenlist.__getitem__)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but to take the actual list shown, and transform it into the list containing the values on the right:

```
sorted(myList, key=str)
```

To undo this operation, regardless of the actual data in the list:

```
>>> myList = ["one", "ten", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
>>> fixlist = sorted(range(1,1+len(myList)), key=str)
>>> [p[1] for p in sorted(zip(fixlist,myList))]
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

Basically, `fixlist` has been re-ordered the same way your data was. So it contains the original index of each element, before they were scrambled. `zip` associates each element from the list with its original index. `sorted` then sorts the pairs, which means they're placed in order of the first element of the pair, which is the original index.

Answer (score 0):

Python's 'list comprehension' would work well here. Looks like you want to sort strings, rather than numbers. So..

```
seq = [str(i) for i in mylist]

>>>print sorted(seq)

['1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...]
```

If you meant numbers (integers) instead of original strings, then-

```
seq = [int(i) for i in mylist]

>>>print sorted(seq)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...]
```

Or if you meant to find an index on the original items so that they would processed be in numerical order:

```
>>>print [seq.index(str(i)) for i in sorted([int(i) for i in seq])]
[0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

Neater one liner for the index

```
>>>print [seq.index(str(i)) for i in sorted(seq, key=int)]
    [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

Comment: This is how it was generated in the first place. The question is looking for a solution to undo this.

Comment: not sure if i am on the right track, yet but it is fun trying